# Log your Work - Jira vs' Azure DevOps Board

Tags: azure-devops

some of our clients using Jira others the Azure DevOps Boards.
By Jira, on Work Items we have a "Work log" tab, where we can log our times.

[image: Jira WorkLog panel]

I'm searching for the same at Azure DevOps Boards, but can't find more as the Effort (Hours) part on Tasks. But this is much weaker... Do we need a plugin or what is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure DevOps does not support daily time-tracking. To enable it, you have to use some external solutions like [7pace Timetracker for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=7pace.Timetracker)